# Extract from multiple regex named groups

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with a text column containing dates in multiple formats. I've written regex for all the formats. I'm able to run the regex individually but I when I try to run them all at once on the dataframe, I keep getting the error
"re.error: redefinition of group name 'month' as group 4; was group 1 at position 66"

```
 d = [{'text':'03/25/93 Total time of visit (in minutes):'}, {'text':'April 11, 1990 CPT Code: 90791: No medical services'},
         {'text':'29 Jan 1994 Primary Care Doctor:'}, {'text':'s1981  Swedish-American Hospital'}]
mdf = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[1,2,3,4])

regexpattern1 = r'(?P<month>\b\d{1,2})[/-](?P<day>\d{1,2})[/-](?P<year>\d{2})\b'
regexpattern2 = r'(?P<month>(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))[.]?[a-z]*(?:,|\s|\-)?(?P<day>\d{2})(?:\-|,|\s)? (?P<year>\d{4})'
regexpattern3 = r'(?P<day>\d{2}) (?P<month>(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))[.]?[a-z]*[,]? (?P<year>\d{4})'
regexpattern4 = r'(?P<month>)(?P<day>)\b[a-za-z]+(?P<year>\d{4})'
# mdf[['month', 'day', 'year']] = mdf['text'].str.extract(regexpattern4) # runs individually
mdf[['month', 'day', 'year']] = mdf['text'].str.extract("|".join([regexpattern1, regexpattern2, regexpattern3, regexpattern4])) # raises error
print(mdf)

Expected Output:
                                                  text month  day year
1           03/25/93 Total time of visit (in minutes):    03   25   93
2  April 11, 1990 CPT Code: 90791: No medical services   Apr   11  1990
3                     29 Jan 1994 Primary Care Doctor:   Jan   29   1994
4                     s1981  Swedish-American Hospital   NaN  NaN  1981
```

Comment: kindly share your expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy Hey, I've posted the expected output in the comments, thank you.

Comment: You're effectively looking for a branch reset which currently only the `regex` module from `PyPi` supports. However, you're not doing anything with the named groups anyway, so just go ahead and throw the names away. Even better yet - as this has been asked a zillion times before - use a library, e.g. `datefinder`.

Comment: Also, I was using the named groups to give the output as columns and I didn't know how to do that for multiple regex so I created columns in the dataframe. The whole point of having named groups was to get the output as dataframe columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dint get quite to what you wanted but this maybe can help
Basically regex `month(and this can be expanded to cover the 12 months)` and extract any digits accompanied by special characters `,\` provided they are not followed by `:`

```
mdf['date']=mdf.text.str.findall('(\b(?:Ma(?:rch)?)|Apr(?:il)?|Jan|[\,\/\d+]+)(?![\d+:])')



mdf.date= [",".join(line) for line in mdf.date.values]#Remove [] brackets
mdf['date']=pd.to_datetime(mdf['date'].str.replace('/', '-'))#.dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')(Coerce to datetime)
```

Extract days, month and year

```
    mdf['day']=mdf.index.day
    mdf['month']=mdf.index.month
    mdf['year']=mdf.index.year
    mdf.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    print(mdf)
                                                text       date  day  month  \
0         03/25/93 Total time of visit (in minutes): 1993-03-25   25      3   
1  April 11 1990 CPT Code: 90791: No medical serv... 1990-04-11   11      4   
2                   29 Jan 1994 Primary Care Doctor: 1994-01-29   29      1   
3                   s1981  Swedish-American Hospital 1981-01-01    1      1   

   year  
0  1993  
1  1990  
2  1994  
3  1981  
​
```

Comment: Thank you for this. My initial objective is that I want the dates from this string and then I have to sort the dates. The initial file that I have is of 500 records and with about 10 different date formats. I was using regex for all the 10 or so date formats and then getting the output as I had put in my expected output in the question. I had created 3 different columns - each for day, month and year to get the date format and then would combine them and perform the sorting.

Comment: See my edits. I have tried to extract date. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Yes, this works for the above 4 rows. I have 500 rows in mine and very different date formats and hence I was using this regular experssions      `code             regexpattern1 = r'(?P<month>\b\d{1,2})[/-](?P<day>\d{1,2})[/-](?P<year>\d{2})\b'
regexpattern2 = r'(?P<month>(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))[.]?[a-z]*(?:,|\s|\-)?(?P<day>\d{2})(?:\-|,|\s)? (?P<year>\d{4})'
regexpattern3 = r'(?P<day>\d{2}) (?P<month>(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))[.]?[a-z]*[,]? (?P<year>\d{4})'
regexpattern4 = r'(?P<month>)(?P<day>)\b[a-za-z]+(?P<year>\d{4})' `

Comment: @Rajat, answers are provided as the information given. I took into consideration the dates provided. I didnt have means to know what  other dates were available.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [**`datefinder`**](https://datefinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import datefinder, pandas as pd, numpy as np

string = """
03/25/93 Total time of visit (in minutes):
April 11, 1990 CPT Code: 90791: No medical services
29 Jan 1994 Primary Care Doctor:
s1981  Swedish-American Hospital
"""

result = []
loop = (line for line in string.split("\n") if line)
for line in loop:
    try:
        date = next(m for m in datefinder.find_dates(line))
    except:
        date = np.nan

    result.append([line, date])

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(result, columns=["text", "date"])
print(df)
```

This yields

```
                                                text       date
0         03/25/93 Total time of visit (in minutes): 1993-03-25
1  April 11, 1990 CPT Code: 90791: No medical ser... 1990-04-11
2                   29 Jan 1994 Primary Care Doctor: 1994-01-29
3                   s1981  Swedish-American Hospital        NaT
```

Your original approach had a couple of issues and you were effectively looking for [**a branch reset**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html).

Comment: Thanks @Jan. This doesn't seem to cover all the cases I have. For eg. cases like: 4, 4/24/98 Relevant Drug History (OR)  Anson General Hospital on 10 Feb 1983 @ 12 AM (OR) 22 Jan 1996 @ 11 AMCommunication with referring physician?: Done. How should I deal with these cases?

Comment: @Rajat: Well,what would you want to extract from this string?

Comment: I want the dates from this string and then I have to sort the dates. The initial file that I have is of 500 records and with about 10 different date formats. I was using regex for all the 10 or so date formats and then getting the output as I had put in my expected output in the question. Let me know how best I can help for you to be able to help me :)